PySpark builtin functions to remove UDF
I have a column whose value is:
"{""ab"": 0.7220268151565864, ""cd"": 0.2681795338834256, ""ef"": 1.0, ""gh"": 1.0, ""ij"": 0.9266362339932378, ""kl"": 0.7002315808130385}"

I am using UDF to convert this into final result which looks like this:
{"ab": 0.7220268151565864, "cd": 0.2681795338834256, "ef": 1.0, "gh": 1.0, "ij": 0.9266362339932378, "kl": 0.7002315808130385}

But this UDF takes a very long time as there are multiple columns like this and I have to run the UDF multiple times. Can someone please help if the final result can be achieved using only PySpark built-in functions so that it can improve the performance?

what is the column type of the last one?

have you tried something like - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace. What is the current function doing ?

You can get the desired output with regexp_replace().
Try this:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [('''"{""ab"": 0.7220268151565864, ""cd"": 0.2681795338834256, ""ef"": 1.0, ""gh"": 1.0, ""ij"": 0.9266362339932378, ""kl"": 0.7002315808130385}"''',
         '''"{""mn"": 0.7220268151565864, ""op"": 0.2681795338834256, ""qr"": 1.0, ""st"": 1.0, ""uv"": 0.9266362339932378, ""wx"": 0.7002315808130385}"''')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2"])
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                                                                                                                        |col2                                                                                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|"{""ab"": 0.7220268151565864, ""cd"": 0.2681795338834256, ""ef"": 1.0, ""gh"": 1.0, ""ij"": 0.9266362339932378, ""kl"": 0.7002315808130385}"|"{""mn"": 0.7220268151565864, ""op"": 0.2681795338834256, ""qr"": 1.0, ""st"": 1.0, ""uv"": 0.9266362339932378, ""wx"": 0.7002315808130385}"|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


for col_name in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col(col_name), r'""', '"'), r'^"|"$', ''))

df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                                                                                                          |col2                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"ab": 0.7220268151565864, "cd": 0.2681795338834256, "ef": 1.0, "gh": 1.0, "ij": 0.9266362339932378, "kl": 0.7002315808130385}|{"mn": 0.7220268151565864, "op": 0.2681795338834256, "qr": 1.0, "st": 1.0, "uv": 0.9266362339932378, "wx": 0.7002315808130385}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

The first expression r'""', '"' means replacing two consecutive double quotes ("") with a single double quote (").
The second expression r'^"|"$', '' means replacing the starting (^") and the ending ("$) double quotes with the empty string ('').

str.replace( '"' * 2, '"' )  should achieve same
